# Comparing incoming credentials against Oracle hashed password

Tags: c#, oracle, hash

I have an Oracle database. I would like to encrypt the incoming password in C# and compare that against the value that is stored in the built in oracle table called sys.user$ specifically the "spare4" column.

Is it possible to do this? I have tried to encrypt the password but it's not generating the same output as the value that is generated in the Oracle database table, so clearly i am missing logic that Oracle applies. Any ideas?

From what i understand the first 40 chars is the hashed password and the last 20 chars is the hashed Salt value.

In Oracle 11g onwards it uses the Salt (no idea how Oracle generates this) and applies to the password and then hashes it using SHA-1 to generate the S: part of the spare4 values according to the following blogs [password hashes](http://marcel.vandewaters.nl/oracle/security/password-hashes) and [Spare 4 tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_spare4.htm)

Here is the current code:

```
    public static string GenerateSaltedSHA1(string plainTextString, int saltSize)
    {
        HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA1Managed();
        var saltBytes = GenerateSalt(saltSize);
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainTextString);

        var plainTextWithSaltBytes = AppendByteArrays(plainTextBytes, saltBytes);
        var saltedSHA1Bytes = algorithm.ComputeHash((byte[]) plainTextWithSaltBytes);
        var saltedSHA1WithAppendedSaltBytes = AppendByteArrays(saltedSHA1Bytes, saltBytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(saltedSHA1WithAppendedSaltBytes);
    }

    private static byte[] GenerateSalt(int saltSize)
    {
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var buff = new byte[saltSize];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        return buff;
    }

   private static byte[] AppendByteArrays(byte[] byteArray1, byte[] byteArray2)
    {
        var byteArrayResult =
            new byte[byteArray1.Length + byteArray2.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < byteArray1.Length; i++)
            byteArrayResult[i] = byteArray1[i];
        for (var i = 0; i < byteArray2.Length; i++)
            byteArrayResult[byteArray1.Length + i] = byteArray2[i];

        return byteArrayResult;
    }
```

I understand that in Oracle there are functions in DBMS_CRYPTO e.g hash that can be used to create a hash based on particular type e.g MD5, SHA-1 etc on the password etc.

If there are much better ways then i am open to suggestions.

Comment: I think you don't want to apply a newly generated salt value.  You want to apply the _same_ salt value from `spare4`.

Comment: You're correct but its not apparent according to their docs/blogs on how Oracle is generating the salt.

Comment: You don't need to know how it is generated.  Just pull it from spare4.  The salt in spare4 would be the plain text salt, not a hash of the salt.  That wouldn't make any sense.  The salt is not "secret".

Answer (score 0):

In case my comments were not clear (or not believed), here is a little SQL statement that will do what you are looking for.  This runs on 12c -- but won't swear it will work with all security options.  If you have an S: part in `sys.user$.spare4`, it probably should work.

```
with trial as 
(SELECT name, 
-- The 1st 20 bytes (40 characters) of the "S" part are the hashed password
substr(substr(spare4,3,60),1,40) hashed_pwd, 
-- The last 10 bytes (20 characters) of the "S" part are the plaintext salt
substr(substr(spare4,3,60),-20) salt, 
-- I want to know if the password for user MYUSERNAME is "MYPASSWORDGUESS"...
'MYPASSWORDGUESS' trial_password
from sys.user$
where name = 'MYUSERNAME' ),
hashit as (
-- This SELECT adds the salt to our trial password and hashes it.
select name, 
       trial_password, 
       hashed_pwd, 
       salt,
       -- The "3" is for the SH1 algorithm
       sys.dbms_crypto.hash(
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(trial_password) || cast (salt as raw(10) ),3) 
          hashed_salted_trial
from trial )
-- If the resulting hash matches what Oracle has stored in spare4, it is good.
SELECT name, 
       trial_password, 
       case when hashed_pwd = hashed_salted_trial 
           then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END password_match
from hashit
;
```

Update "MYUSERNAME" and "MYPASSWORDGUESS" as needed for your database.

#### UPDATE

> > Based on my original code in C# is there an equivalent way of doing the following in C#? sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(trial_password) || cast (salt as raw(10) ),3)

`utl_raw.cast_to_raw(trial_password)` is doing the same thing as `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainTextString)` in your post.  The goal of each is to take your guess at the password and convert it into byte.

`cast(salt as raw(10))` does not have an equivalent in your post.  More on this later.

`||` is the way you concatenate `RAW` values in Oracle.  It serves the same purpose as `AppendByteArrays` in your post.

`sys.dbms_crypto.hash(..., 3)` is how you generate a 160-bit SHA-1 hash in Oracle.  I guess that is what `algorithm.ComputeHash` does in your post.

So, the only thing you are missing in your code is an equivalent for `cast(salt as raw(10))`.

As we discussed, you cannot generate your own salt for this.  You *must* use the salt that is encoded in `user$.spare4`.  That would be the last 20 characters of the "S:" part of that field. It looks like this: `FA338B110F78548CCB44`.  Every two characters form a hexadecimal BYTE that gives you one of the bytes of your salt.  So, in my example, the 1st byte of the salt (given by "FA") is 15 (for "F") x16+10 (for "A") = 250.

That is hopefully enough logic for you to implement in C#.  However, it is not really necessary that you do so, because the input value for the salt can only come from `user$.spare4` in the Oracle database.  Since you gave to go to Oracle anyway, it is just as simple to

```
SELECT cast(substr(substr(spare4,3,60),-20) as RAW) FROM user$
```

as it is to just

```
SELECT spare4 FROM user$
```

and the do the rest in C#.  You might as well let Oracle do what it is good at.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate your input and example. Based on my original code in C# is there an equivalent way of doing the following in C#?
sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(trial_password) || cast (salt as raw(10) ),3)

Comment: I updated my answer with a response to your comment.